# Outlook Icon - Disable unread email notification

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I recently upgraded to the latest version of Outlook.
Microsoft Outlook Version 1.2023.425.600 (Production).
Client Version is 20230428009.14 .

This latest version of Outlook replaced the older taskbar icon.  I had previously configured the older taskbar icon to **NOT** notify me when a new message arrived.  The new version of Outlook imported all my setting except the unread notification of the Outlook icon.  Below is an example of the icon when unread messages are in the inbox.

[image]

Edited to include the current settings available in this version of Outlook

[image]

Does anyone know how I can set the Outlook taskbar icon to NOT change when unread messages are in the inbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really the ***latest version*** of Outlook (the Classic Outlook as we know it), it is the [**New Outlook**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/getting-started-with-the-new-outlook-for-windows-656bb8d9-5a60-49b2-a98b-ba7822bc7627) which is a very much limited version of Outlook, basically Outlook Web installed as a PWA.

(The settings of this thing is what you would have when you go to https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/options, which is why it would not have anything pertaining to local settings of the application itself.)

To be honest, personally I do not have the envelope unread badge when using the New Outlook (and I've seen others complain that they don't either, one example [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Outlook/comments/12t87b4/new_outlook_for_pc_not_showing_unread_badge/)), but I tried it in Windows 10, so maybe on Windows 11 it's there.

The real solution for you is to switch back to the normal Classic Outlook by toggling the ***New Outlook*** toggle on the upper-right side of Outlook:
[image]

(If you want a modern design with the Classic Outlook, you can try to the ***Office visual refresh***, after switching back, see [**The new look of Office**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/the-new-look-of-office-a6cdf19a-b2bd-4be1-9515-d74a37aa59bf))

Comment: Agree with Yisroel Tech, it's suggested that you could switch to legacy Outlook.

Comment: Agreed.  I switched back.  Thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the *NEW* Outlook version. The classic outlook version had a setting for this.

The following is not an Outlook specific answer, but you can disable *all* badges in the taskbar in one go. This can be done via the Windows settings.
Uncheck the following:
`Settings > Personalisation > Taskbar > Show badges on taskbar apps` (that last item might be hidden under taskbar behaviour).

[image]

I haven't found a way yet to disable specific badges such as the Outlook badge. Maybe they'll add that setting back in the future.

In my case, going back to the classic version wasn't possible (the support for shared mailboxes is much better), but I'm not a fan of notifications anywhere. This is a good workaround.